# Cannot submit form values correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I have a form which have questions and answers and it holds: `student_id` , `survey_id` , `question_id` , `answer_id`. and i expect each form should save records equals to the questions.
I have two problems:

1- only first attribute (`student_id`) in my create action saved with `0` value , and the other attributes saved as `Null`

2- the form submits 2 extra records. my current form has 3 questions when i answer the 3 questions i got 5 records inside the database (and the first record only has null values except for `student_id = 0` and the other records all attributes null values.

controller:

```
def create
#student_id saved as 0 and the rest attributes saved as Null
#always save two extra records with null value even when i answer all questions
    params[:subject_survey].each do |student, survey, question, answer|
        @sv_sub = SubjectSurvey.create(student_id: student["student_id"],
    survey_id: survey["survey_id"],
    question_id: question,
    answer_id: answer)
    end

    if @sv_sub.save
        redirect_to surveys_path, notice: "Success."
    else
        render :new, notice: "Failed."
    end
end
```

server log:

```
#when answering three questions:

Started POST "/subject_surveys" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-14 21:54:09 +0200
Processing by SubjectSurveysController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"C8w1p+tQCTY25SJU5TGJcqCqRoUw1TvVBjEJgpjPMPc=", "subject_survey"=>{"student_id"=>"1", "survey_id"=>"1", "2"=>{"answer_id"=>"7"}, "3"=>{"answer_id"=>"14"}, "4"=>{"answer_id"=>"19"}}}

#when answering one question:

Started POST "/subject_surveys" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-14 21:50:29 +0200
Processing by SubjectSurveysController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"C8w1p+tQCTY25SJU5TGJcqCqRoUw1TvVBjEJgpjPMPc=", "subject_survey"=>{"student_id"=>"1", "survey_id"=>"1", "2"=>{"answer_id"=>"7"}}}
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag('/subject_surveys', method: :post, class: 'form-horizontal' ) do %>    
    <% q = 0 %>
    <% Survey.find(1).questions.order("questions.id asc").each do |question| %>
        <% q += 1%>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'subject_survey[student_id]', "#{current_user.student.id}" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'subject_survey[survey_id]', '1' %>
    <h6>Q<%= q %>- <%= question.content %></h6>
    <div class="clearfix"></div><div class="clearfix"></div>
    <% if question.question_type == "#{Question::CHECK}" %>
        <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
            <%= check_box_tag "subject_survey[#{question.id}][answer_id][]", "#{answer.id}" %>
            <%= answer.content  %>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <% end %>
    <% elsif question.question_type == "#{Question::RADIO}" %>
        <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
            <%= radio_button_tag "subject_survey[#{question.id}][answer_id]", "#{answer.id}" %>
            <%= answer.content %>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% if question.id == Survey.find(1).questions.order("questions.id asc").last.id %>
        <br>
    <% else %>
        <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #000000;">
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-actions no-margin">
        <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-info pull-right" %>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one thing I saw first is that you don't need `survey["survey_id"]` and `student["student_id"]` in your controller. You have already mapped them and you only need `survey` and `student` respectively.

On the other hand, each `question` has an answer hash assigned to it. And so, you should treat is as such.

This means, that in your initial mapping

```
params[:subject_survey].each do |student, survey, question, answer|
```

the last argument (answer) has no place. Anyhow, it's not the most right to do this, so look below.

Also, the 3rd argument, question, is a bit fuzzy... It's not passed as "question", but as a number pointing to a value. You should make it an array.

In your form, change this:

```
<%= check_box_tag "subject_survey[#{question.id}][answer_id][]", "#{answer.id}" %>
```

into this (no need to tell the form that the value is tagged "answer_id", you already know that, so we get rid of the `[answer_id]` part)

```
<%= check_box_tag "subject_survey[questions][#{question.id}]", "#{answer.id}" %>
```

Then, in your controller action

```
def create
    params[:subject_survey][:questions].each do |question, answer|
        @sv_sub = SubjectSurvey.create(
            student_id: params[:subject_survey][:student_id],
            survey_id: params[:subject_survey][:survey_id],
            question_id: question,
            answer_id: answer)
    end
    ....
```

Comment: thanks for reply , i am getting this `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass` for questions.each

Comment: thats the params `  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"J5ZcUyKbnE7r3gxdeMiP7b7FVZ10Kh7BhUwaq5Mddew=", "subject_survey"=>{"student_id"=>"1", "survey_id"=>"1", "questions"=>{"2"=>{"answer_id"=>"7"}, "3"=>{"answer_id"=>"10"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}`

Comment: Note that in the form, [answer_id] is removed... Not quite sure if you should also remove [] right after it

Comment: please note that i also modified radio tag as this:
`<%= radio_button_tag "subject_survey[questions][#{question.id}][answer_id]", "#{answer.id}" %>`

Comment: Could you paste the new error, exactly as it appears?

Comment: okay final issue that i cannot fetch the answer id, the rest is saved correctly, i tried answer[:answer_id] with no luck

Comment: Solved , by using this <%= radio_button_tag "subject_survey[questions][#{question.id}][answer_id]", "#{answer.id}" %> , i will do the same with checkbox

Comment: i used those: `question_id: question,
            answer_id: answer[:answer_id]`

Comment: where i should read about this feature specifically ? because its my first time to use a create action instead of the normal ones. a book ? a video ?

Comment: Well, it's not a feature.. It's a conversion. If you put [answer_id] in your form, it will be the key to the hash passed to the controller, and the actual answer_id will be the value... If you omit [answer_id] in the form, you do not need to do  answer_id: answer[:answer_id]. Read the form helpers api, search a lot in here and keep your hands on. The only sure way to learn